# Picklist Value not getting inserted in Save method

Tags: apex

My page

```
 <apex:pageblocksectionItem >
            <apex:outputlabel value="Date Format"/>
             <Apex:selectlist value="{!dateval}" size="1" style="width:100px;">
               <Apex:selectoptions value="{!datevalues}"></Apex:selectoptions>
             </Apex:selectlist>
          </apex:pageblocksectionItem>       
          <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
             <Apex:outputLabel value="Counter Seed"></Apex:outputLabel>
             <apex:inputtext value="{!Settings.Counter__c}" maxlength="10" />
          </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

My class is

```
string dateval='yyyy';
public void setdateval(string S){this.dateval= S;}
public string getdateval(){return dateval;}

public list<selectoption> getdatevalues(){
    list<selectoption> Value = new list<selectoption>();
    Value.add(new Selectoption('dd-mm-yyyy','dd-mm-yyyy'));
    value.add(new selectoption('mm-dd-yyyy','mm-dd-yyyy'));
     value.add(new selectoption('mm/dd/yyyy','mm/dd/yyyy'));
}
 public void SaveSetting(){
 Sett.Date_Format__c = this.dateval;
 Sett.Counter__c = Settings.Counter__c;
}
```

here whence I click on save text field is inserted but picklist value is not inserted.I need to get picklist value also inserted.how can I do it.

Comment: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_selectList.htm.   I was looking at this example and we seems to intialise the string with 'yyyy'.I guess lets just have String there and then the setter must set that thing

Comment: Also please debug inside the setter to see whether the picklist value selected comes back in controller or not .

Comment: I am wondering if you need to perform some DML to update your custom setting in your 'SaveSetting' method? e.g. upsert Sett;

Comment: Andrew its good point actually.Thanks.Yes i see no Update statement also

Comment: `If(SettingsSize.size()==0){insert Settings;                                    ApexPages.Message UpdateSuccess = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.INFO, 'Invoice Settings inserted Successfully');ApexPages.addMessage(UpdateSuccess);
}If(SettingsSize.size()==0){insert Settings;                                    ApexPages.Message UpdateSuccess = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.INFO, 'Invoice Settings inserted Successfully');ApexPages.addMessage(UpdateSuccess);
}if (SettingsSize.size()==1){update Settings; }` in Savesettings()

Answer (score 1):

Try a different construction for the getter/setter of dateVal:

```
public class YourClass {
  public String dateVal {
    get { return dateVal; }
    set { dateVal = value; }
  }
}
```

This is from the SFDC Apex doc on properties. 'value' is an implicit keyword referring to the value passed by the VF page (or any caller)